# Rerender component with variable global

Tags: vue.js

I have a global test variable in app.js:

```
Vue.prototype.$test = 10;
```

Then I use in parent page (Menu.vue) for route-view like this:

```
<router-view :key="$test" ></router-view>
```

And I try to change the global variable value (test) in the child component: MyContact.vue so that the "route-view" is re-rendered:

```
<label v-on:click="setRouteId(item.writer_id)"> Change </label>

setRouteId: function(id){
     this.$test = 11;
},
```

The resulting "route-view" is not re-rendered. I do not know why.

Comment: It's not supposed to re-render. $test is not reactive.

Answer (score 0):

Wonder why you need to re-render the whole router view on click.
In case you want to re-render router-view on change url, let use:

```
<router-view :key="route.path"></path>
```

If you really want to re-render router-view on every single click, try store key in vuex, and watch it to change router-view's key on change:

```
<router-view :key="keyRouter"></router-view>  

watch: {
  "$store.state.key"(val) {
    this.keyRouter = val;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this way is always re-render, i only want to re-render in some specific cases. Because I have 2 nested menus, when operating on the submenu, only the content in the submenu changes, the content in the parent menu is not changed. So I want to re-render the parent menu in some cases so that it doesn't get re-rendered in unnecessary cases.